# X509Certificate2.Verify() method always return false for the valid certificate

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I am using smart card for authentication.

The SecurityTokenService (authentication service) is hosted on my machine only. The smart card has a valid certificate and it's root certificate is also installed in Local Computer store on my machine.

When I use `X509Certificate2.Verify` method to validate the certificate in my service, it always return `false`.

**Can someone help me to understand why X509Certificate2.Verify() method always return false?**

Note:
I used `X509Chain` and checked for all the flags (`X509VerificationFlags.AllFlags`). When I build the chanin, it returns `true` with `ChainStatus` as `RevocationStatusUnknown`.

---

### EDIT 1:

I observed that `X509Certificate2.Verify()`  method returns `true` if i write this code in windows form application. It returns `false` only in the service side code. Why so? Strange but true!

Answer (score 4):

The X509VerificationFlags values are suppressions, so specifying `X509VerificationFlags.AllFlags` actually prevents Build from returning false in most situations.

The `RevocationStatusUnknown` response seems particularly relevant.  Whichever certificate it is reporting that for cannot be verified to be not revoked.  The `Verify` method can be modeled as

```
public bool Verify()
{
    using (X509Chain chain = new X509Chain())
    {
        // The defaults, but expressing it here for clarity
        chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
        chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.ExcludeRoot;
        chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime = DateTime.Now;
        chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;

        return chain.Build(this);
    }
}
```

Which, since it is not asserting `X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreCertificateAuthorityRevocationUnknown` or `X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreEndRevocationUnknown` while requesting an X509RevocationMode other than `None`, fails.

First, you should identify which certificate(s) in the chain is(/are) failing:

```
using (X509Chain chain = new X509Chain())
{
    // The defaults, but expressing it here for clarity
    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.ExcludeRoot;
    chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime = DateTime.Now;

    chain.Build(cert);

    for (int i = 0; i < chain.ChainElements.Count; i++)
    {
        X509ChainElement element = chain.ChainElements[i];

        if (element.ChainElementStatus.Length != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error at depth {i}: {element.Certificate.Subject}");

            foreach (var status in element.ChainElementStatus)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  {status.Status}: {status.StatusInformation}}}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you look at any failing certificate in the Windows CertUI (double-click the .cer in Explorer or in the Certificates MMC Snap-In), look for a field named "CRL Distribution Points". These are the URLs that will be retrieved during runtime. Perhaps your system has a data egress restriction that doesn't allow those particular values to be queried for.  You can always try issuing a web request from your web service to see if it can fetch the URLs without the context of being in the certificate subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is due to the proxy server and some security settings in my organization. I cannot give valid reason why it works from WinForm client and why does not from code hosted under IIS.

But the fact I want to let readers know is that `Verify()` method worked on server side code too when I hosted service in IIS running on the machine outside my usual domain! So you may check if the firewall settings of your domain/organization is coming in you way.

Comment: WinForm client would be working under your domain credentials and in IIS the credentials would be different. May be that can be one of the reasons. Try enabling windows authentication in the IIS and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Web application is working under `NETWORK SERVICE` account. That user has access to certificate. But yes, your point is valid; this is often the reason why Verify() method fails from IIS web application.